# problems with git bash on windows. i can't access folders on git bash for windows

Tags: windows, git-bash

i bought a course from codecademy and at beginner was a lesson about git  bash. I install it , but if i want to change directories with "cd" i cant't.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WGFX.png)
Also , when i double-click on shortcut  the program doesn't run.

Comment: I don't think your `Desktop` directory in in the Git Bash root.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to you home directory first

```
$ cd
```

then

```
$ pwd
/c/Users/yourname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going to you root directory with : cd / (make sure you add a space between cd and /)

Then do cd yourfilename/yourfilename....you can add multiple directories

Make sure your spelling is correct

Few other tips :
To navigate to your home directory use "cd ~".
To navigate to the previous directory  use "cd -"